# Docker run NodeJS App throws error cannot find module

Tags: node.js, dockerfile

I am new to docker build feature. I am trying to create docker image for my node.js application, however I am facing issue.
1) It shows image is create but when I am trying to docker run its give error like

```
"module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '
```

I think there is some issue with my docker file. Which I have created but I didn't get what exactly issue is 
my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update -y 
RUN apt-get install g++ -y 
RUN apt install curl -y 
RUN curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x — Node.js 8 LTS "Carbon" |  bash -
RUN apt-get install --yes nodejs
RUN apt-get install --yes build-essential
# check the path 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE  9012
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

Also see the my package.json for more info. of modules.

```
{
  "name": "service",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "description": "test",
  "author": {
    "name": "caitayl"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.8.1",
    "config": "^1.28.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "~2.0.0",
    "ejs": "^2.7.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fabric-ca-client": "~1.4.0",
    "fabric-network": "~1.4.0",
    "firebase": "^6.4.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.4.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "json-server": "^0.15.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "method-override": "^2.3.10",
    "mongodb": "^3.4.1",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.1",
    "nexmo": "^2.4.1",
    "node-gyp": "^5.0.3",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.13.0",
    "node-rest-client": "^3.1.0",
    "os": "^0.1.1",
    "paypal-rest-sdk": "^1.8.1",
    "qs": "^6.8.0",
    "sendotp": "^1.2.9",
    "socket.io": "^2.2.0",
    "winston": "^2.4.2",
    "winston-mongodb": "^2.0.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: You insist on node v.8 ?

Comment: hi@num8er could you please elaborate more? so I can fix it

Comment: I'm saying You want nodejs 8 or latest LTS?

Comment: Yes I want only node.js 8 version so I install that one only

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why You make nodejs image from ubuntu when there are already [official ones](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/).

I see issue - You've overengineered You Dockerfile with unnecessary steps.

Fix Your Dockerfile and try again:

```
FROM node:8-alpine3.9

RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache g++ make python python-dev
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm i

COPY . .

EXPOSE  9012
CMD node app.js
```

From last collaboration I found that it was a typo in code where You required file from not existing folder.

```
"module.js:550 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module '../dFarmUserService/controllers/ClientRegisterController'
```

So fixed it together :)

Comment: Hi @num8er, I have tried above docker file and its create images however still give same error "module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../dFarmUserService/controllers/ClientRegisterController'

Comment: It's issue in Your code. find the file where You require `dFarmUserService/controllers/ClientRegisterController` and put that file in Your question.

Comment: I can however the code in file is big so I think stackflow not allow for that

Comment: @Abhirock Add me to skype: `anarjafarov`  and let's collaborate

Comment: Are you sure?? you want to help me from go of  out of box

Comment: @Abhirock Yes, I'm sure, since I have doubts it will end with fixing of 1 line.

Comment: I couldn't find in skype@ anarjafarov

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204962/discussion-between-abhirock-and-num8er).

Comment: Thanks for the help its great way to help:-)